# What the library is required to use @Verify annotation in JAVA?

Tags: java, junit, annotations, verify

What the library is required to use `@Verify` annotation in JAVA? 
What the import string should look like? 
I added mockito-core.jar and mockito-java8.jar, but @Verify annotation is still in red.

It's used in the code that verifies the title of an opened page:

```
@Path("http://localhost:8080/search.html")
                @Verify(title   =   "Search")
                public  class   SearchForm  {
                                @FindBy(css =   "input[name='q']")
                                private WebElement  query;
                                @FindBy(css =   "input[type='submit']")
                                private WebElement  submit;
                                public  void    searchFor(String    text)   {
                                                query.sendKeys(text);
                                                submit.click();
                                }
                }
```

Comment: Where did you find the code using that annotation? What are you expecting with it? Annotation are like class, out of context we can't guess the library

Comment: I found it in the book about Selenium Web Driver. I added code to the question.